# Creating a dynamic multi-layered image for the web

Tags: javascript, css, graphics, photoshop

I have a multi-layered image in Photoshop that I would like to use on the web. The aim is to have a number of buttons to show/hide the various layers.

My initial thought was to export each layer as a transparent <strike>GIF</strike> PNG, stack the images using CSS and use Javascript to toggle the visibility of each layer.

Is there a better way to achieve this? I am particularly interested to hear of any software or Javascript libraries to simplify this process.

Many thanks.

Edit:
To clarify, the image in question is a map with various outlines and shaded areas to overlay, so I will only need basic control of layer opacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stack each layer into one large image. In your front-end code create a frame the size of the layer with your stacked image as the background.

Create the buttons and use jquery to trigger a background shift relative to the button that is pushed. It will appear the image is changing, but it is just shifting the background. This will save on consecutive image loads, making the UI appear quick and seamless.

Comment: The problem is, any combination of layers needs to be displayed at any one time. Sorry, I have just edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: Create buttons that trigger different divs that either display or hide their counterparts. Create a container frame div positioned relative. Inside this place your image inside absolute divs within the container, z-index them in the order you wish the layers to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the ::before and ::after and -webkit-mask-image property to help you create you multi layered image.

Or just stack png with absolute position and your png needs to be in 24bit mod, by the way.

Comment: Thanks. Is `-webkit-mask-image` browser specific? I need to maintain compatibility with all of the major browsers.

Comment: yes everything coming with a dash vendor, is specific to the vendor. Bu the ::before and ::after are pseudo elements from the CSS3, and :before and :after are part of CSS 2.1. If you have a doubt about browser support you could use this great ressource : http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [P5.js](https://p5js.org/reference/) to create a canvas and then simply load each layer on top of each other. In p5.js, you can assign each image to a variable, show it using image() inside draw() and use conditional logic to hide it when a button is clicked, its very simple.

Here is an example showing how to display images.
https://editor.p5js.org/ivymeadows/sketches/SyKvIlVA-